# SAS Format in calculation

Tags: sas

I am creating New variable as AGE.The CUTOFF value is 100 and it is divided by 12 so the value is exactly 8.3333.....But Few freshness values are 8.3333333. I have to pick the value of SEGMENT if FRESHNESS>= 100/12, but its picking AMU where freshness is 8.3333... The format of FRESHNESS is F12.9 and CUTOFF is BEST12.

```
  data new;
    set SEGMENT_AGE;
    IF Freshness< CUTOFF/12 THEN AGE=AMU;
                         ELSE AGE=SEGMENT;
    RUN;
```

I tried with different format making cutoff to F12.9 , still its not working

Comment: A format has no effect on the underlying value, it's for display purpose only. SAS uses floating point internally for all numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I dont know why am not getting the values as I desired?

Comment: The difference of CutOff_month/12-Freshness is 2.960306E-15, How it will be?  CutOff_month/12=8.3333 and Freshness is 8.3333

Comment: Try removing all formatting and looking at the raw data, it might be evident this way. Also, include some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into an issue of floating point precision.  If a number is a repeating decimal (in binary), you may have two different values (the higher or lower - ie, 0.333333333333333333 or 0.3333333333333333333334) depending on how it was arrived at.  IE:

```
1-(1/3) - (1/3) = 0.33333333333333333334
0+(1/3)         = 0.33333333333333333333
```

So do not assume it is precisely equal just because it looks like it should be.  Further, some numbers in decimal that are not repeating decimals are repeating in binary - 7/10 for example is 0.7 decimal but is not storable precisely in binary.

You should compare rounded numbers if you need to compare precisely; for example,

```
if round(freshness,0.001) < round(cutoff/12,0.001) ...
```

should result in your calculations matching your expectations.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with it and will let you the result